# Did Worf actually return to his original universe in 'Parallels'?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

At the start of the episode, we see Worf return from the competition to an unwelcome surprise party and Troi replaces a wall mounted shield near the door to his quarters with Data's painting.

Worf then encounters Geordi for the first time in the episode and shenanigans ensue.

At the end, after Worf has supposedly returned to his original universe, there is no surprise party, and the shield is missing. Doesn't this indicate he's still in a different universe?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All indications are that he did return to his correct universe. The shuttle he boarded is [described](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/263.txt) as having exactly the right quantum signature.

> **RIKER:** (re: shuttle) *Did they send the right shuttle?*
>
> **DATA:** *Yes. Its quantum signature matches Commander Worf's precisely.*

We're told that if Worf does the thing that he did, it should return him to his correct universe.

> **DATA:** *It was Worf's shuttlecraft which traversed the fissure and weakened the barriers between quantum realities. If he re-enters the fissure in his original shuttle, and emits a broad-spectrum warp field -- it may be enough to seal the fissure and stop additional realities from emerging into our own.*
>
> **RIKER:** *Then what? How do we get the Enterprises that are already here back to where they belong?*
>
> **DATA:** *In theory, the act of sealing the fissure should also restore the barriers between quantum states. (beat) The ships would return to their own realities.*

I think we can also reasonably assume that Worf reported what happened to the crew and they scanned him. Since quantum signatures are scannable, if his was wrong it would have resulted in them working to send him back like they did in the first place.

---

As to why there are discrepancies at the end of the show, Data makes it clear that Worf didn't *start* shifting realities when he got back to the Enterprise. He'd already made a jump from one reality to another merely by being in close proximity to the quantum fissure. By the time he got back to the Enterprise he was already in an alternate universe.

> **DATA:** *When Worf's shuttlecraft made contact with the quantum fissure, I believe its warp engines caused a small break in the barriers between quantum realties. Worf was thrown into a state of quantum flux. He immediately began to shift to other realities.*

Comment: I think that part of the joke here was that in the *right* universe, there is no surprise party.